# Getting error while parsing xml through sax

Tags: python, python-3.2

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 1. File "C:\Python32\saxparser.py", line 19, in <module>
    parser.parse('xmlfile.xml')
 2. File "C:\Python32\lib\xml\sax\expatreader.py", line 107, in parse
    xmlreader.IncrementalParser.parse(self, source)
 3. File "C:\Python32\lib\xml\sax\xmlreader.py", line 125, in parse
    self.close()
 4. File "C:\Python32\lib\xml\sax\expatreader.py", line 217, in close
    self.feed("", isFinal = 1)
 5.  File "C:\Python32\lib\xml\sax\expatreader.py", line 211, in feed
    self._err_handler.fatalError(exc)
 6. File "C:\Python32\lib\xml\sax\handler.py", line 38, in fatalError
    raise exception
xml.sax._exceptions.SAXParseException: xmlfile.xml:26:13: no element found
```

Comment: Please provide the part of your program you think is causing this, and what you expect it to do. Preferably create a small program that demonstrates the problem in fewer than 50 lines or so.

Answer (score 0):

This error means you tried to parse an empty file.